# ComponentInfo{packgname.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception

Whenever I run my android application I get an exception:

```
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{packgname/de.fau.fsahoy.android.api15.Activities.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.fau.fsahoy.android.api15.Activities.LoginActivity
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packgname.Activities.LoginActivity
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
05-07 12:03:55.356: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  ... 11 more
```

However, in my AndroidManifest.xml there imho nothing wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.fau.fsahoy.android.api15"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/fsa_launcher"
        android:label="@string/AppName">

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/AppName">
            <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activities.MainMenuActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.ProfileActivity"></activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

I'm going crazy about that issue and trying to resolve it for the last 3 hours or so :<

Currently I am rebuilding the app by copy and pasting the code over to another clean project. I hope that works. Anyway, I see that many people have that issue. What is it?

Comment: are you sure the package name of the activity is correct (btw packages are in lower case usually, and singular)

Comment: tell me package name of your  `LoginActivity`...i mean first line?

Comment: Can you show us the code (Mainly the constructor area) of the LoginActivity class?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and re-building from scratch? (Project -> Clean)

Comment: Yes, multiple times. Showing some code is also not helpful I think.
I rebuilt the project from scratch and c&p the code over to the new one. Magically it worked then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a new Android Project and manually copy and pasted the code from the old project.

Magically then - it worked :)

Might not be the best solution - especially for large projects with a huge codebase. Yet, it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar "poltergeist" in my code. I don't understand the reason but it seems to be related with my activity extending `FragmentActivity` and having a method with the following signature: `public boolean isResumed()`.
I renamed the method and it worked.